# Fading Text In and Out - Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency, video

I'm having difficulty getting text in my video to fade in and out. Currently, if I add text, it simply pops up without any transition.

I've attempted doing something similar to fading video clips in and out by using color and gamma crossing, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Could anyone help me understand what I need to do in order to get this to work? I noticed there's an option to mess with text opacity, but it doesn't allow me to make the opacity rise and fall throughout the timeline.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Minor Update: It looks like keyframes are a step in the right direction. There's a little ball to the right of the opacity value that saves that value for the current position of your selection in the timeline.

Comment: Ok, it looks like keyframing definitely works! Lower values seamlessly transition to higher ones and vice-versa. In case anyone else has a possible answer, I'll leave this question open. Please feel free to offer any alternative solutions in case mine is a bit unconventional.

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest beta version of Blender https://builder.blender.org/download/ - it will have fades in the Add menu:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I look forward to trying it.